# Is MOSIX the easiest way to build a redundant system?

Tags: linux, cluster, failover, failovercluster

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to build a server with HA.

I looked into Linux-HA, Heartbeat, Mesos.

I then found MOSIX. I don't know if it's a thing from the past that no one uses, but wouldn't make it a no-brainer to create a high-availability cluster that would be totally transparent to the software (and therefore easier to setup and configure)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that mesos + marathon would be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosix has a different purpose. It's meant for parallel systems for HPC (high performance computing), not as a high availability solution.

Comment: thanks! wouldn't it make an installation HA, though?

Comment: @F.Ronati: The requirements of HPC computing are quite different from (load balanced) HA systems for general services as e.g. web servers so this would be a poor choice.